# powerpoint: completely hide tooltips over shapes with hyperlink

Tags: vba, powerpoint, touchscreen

Using Powerpoint 2010, we are developing a touchscreen application to be displayed in the Kiosk mode.

Now I have here a powerpoint slide with a transparent,invisible shape that has a hyperlink to a PDF File.

On click, the Acrobat Reader opens and shows a PDF file. So far, so good.

However, if someone moves the mouse pointer or the finger over the button (+ transparent shape), there always appears a big tooltip displaying the filename, such as "\mypath\longsubdir\myfile.pdf" - and this tooltip is really annoying.

*Is there a way to hide the tooltip?* There does not seem to be an easy way to hide it, using the context menu of the hyperlinked shape.

Or should I try some workaround (using transparent command buttons instead of shapes, or similar. Using the VBA APi of the shape...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't have powerpoint 2010 but 2007 here, but when I create a shape, click on the hyperlink button, following screen appears (or something similar at least):
[Image link, can not post images yet.(no popups)](http://www.powerpoint-2010.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/insert-hyperlink-in-powerpoint.gif)
In the top right corner, you have a button "Screentip". Click this button, fill in a space or even nothing at all and your screentip will only show up empty.

Or if you indeed want to truly remove the tooltip altogether, then I do recommend to use some vba/macro. Create a new macro, insert these lines of code:

```
Dim myShell As Object
Set myShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
myShell.Run "C:\MyPDF.pdf"
```

Change the path to the pdf of course. Then add an action to your shape and link it to the macro that you created.

Comment: Clicking the screentip button, filling in a space or even nothing at all will *not completely* remove the tooltip.

I think your VBA snippet will open two more windows, a command window and this will launch an acrobat reader window. Not sure if this is the right thing to do in a touchscreen application. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @knb You are right about the screentip not being completely removed. But if you try the VBA code, you'll see that it does not open a command window. It creates (a reference to) an object of the shell-application. From there, it will directly start your pdf with the standard program. No cmd.exe will be launched.

Answer (score 0):

Powerpoint already has an option that hides all screen tips.
Go to the menu: [File - Option - General], Under 'User interface option'
Change the '**ScreenTips style**' option to '**Don't Show ScreenTips**'

or You can try the following macro code 
to force all ScreenTips to just show 'little blank circles':

```
Sub ForceScreenTipsToBlank()

    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim lnk As Hyperlink

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each lnk In sld.Hyperlinks

            lnk.ScreenTip = vbCr  'or " " to show blank

        Next lnk
    Next sld
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, Changing to [lnk.ScreenTip=""] doesn't remove screen-tips.
You have to re-add hyperlinks with no ScreenTip or manually remove ScreenTips in the dialog box.